# Vertical Scrolling in Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, custom-masterpage, public-website

Im having problems with scrolling in sharepoint site. I am fairly new to Sharepoint and have taken over the UX responsibilities for a site. The problem that Im having is that the scrollbar does not reach the bottom of the Site Settings > Site Navigation page. Users are forced to tab down to the bottom and when a user reaches the bottom of the page, the scrolling does no longer reaches the top of the page.

Comment: is this a public site you could share the URL to for us to look at?

Comment: Does this page have any custom layout and or css on it?

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint 2010 is build in a "special" way, so the entire design (CSS/HTML) and javascript is dependent on each other for everything to work fluently.

I'm assuming you are using a custom masterpage, since this problem hardly ever occurs when using the default v4.master.

The structure of your masterpage after the ribbon should always contain the following DIVs:

- **s4-workspace (class)**
- **s4-bodycontainer (class)**
- **MSO_ContentDiv (id)** (important that this DIV has  *runat=server* for Toolpane to display properly in editmode)
- **MSO_ContentTable (id) with s4-ca (class)**.

Have these mentioned DIVs containing each other in that order and scroll should go from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a CSS/HTML bug. If it's only showing on that one page, it could be a CSS margin issue. Without a screenshot and/or snippets of the applicable CSS/HTML it'd be pretty difficult for anyone to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed problems before when using Google Chrome with SP2010. The scroll bars would only show up sporatically. Oftentimes it could be "fixed" by just refreshing the page.

Does this sound like what you're seeing as well?

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be the right fix. Myself and my users are predominantly in an IE8 environment and strangely enough this is only hapenning on one page.